# ListBox Eventhandler for Powershell-Script needed

Tags: powershell, user-interface, listbox

Im trying to make a powershellscript using XAML Objects, that can be used to configure AD-Users.
My goal right now is to add a live search for a specific textbox. The script uses the input from the textbox, compares it to AD-Users and displays the output in a listbox. What I need is an eventhandler, that activates when I click any Item in the listbox

The last part is the relevant piece.
I'm grateful for any help.

```
        $inputXML = @"
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="HHI Helpdesk Helper" Height="350" Width="654.604" Icon="C:\Users\hoesl\Pictures\logo.png" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
        <Grid Background="#FFA0A0A0">
            <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="628">
                <TabItem Header="Enable Admin Account">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <Label x:Name="label" Content="User : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Service-Tag : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label2" Content="Set Password : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <Calendar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="434,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,127,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="116" Width="410">
                            <TextBlock.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3A3A3"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </TextBlock.Background>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="434,182,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.482,0.542" Height="27" Width="178" OpacityMask="White">
                            <TextBlock.Background>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE0DFDF"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </TextBlock.Background>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Label x:Name="label3" Content="Valid Until : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="346,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Keep old password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="220,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Apply" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="435,215,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Height="29" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFA6A5A5"/>
                        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="125" Margin="95,32,0,-0.2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Visibility="Hidden" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Re-Activate Admin Account">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <Label x:Name="label4" Content="User : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="85,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,13,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <Calendar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="420,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="168" Width="188"/>
                        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="420,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" Height="29"/>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Content="New User" Header="New User"/>
                <TabItem Header="Unlock User"/>
                <TabItem Header="New Extern User">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="111,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="111,49,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="111,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="111,127,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="111,167,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label5" Content="Firstname :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label6" Content="Lastname :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label7" Content="E-Mail-Address :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label8" Content="Manager :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label9" Content="Ticketnumber :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="175" Width="318" Background="#FF323131" Foreground="White" Cursor="Wait"/>
                        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="503,212,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Height="31"/>

                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>

        </Grid>
    </Window>

    "@ 

    $inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
    [xml]$XAML = $inputXML
    #Read XAML

    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
    try{
        $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
    }
    catch{
        Write-Warning "Unable to parse XML, with error: $($Error[0])`n Ensure that there are NO SelectionChanged or TextChanged properties in your textboxes (PowerShell cannot process them)"
        throw
    }

    #===========================================================================
    # Load XAML Objects In PowerShell
    #===========================================================================

    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{"trying item $($_.Name)";
        try {Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop}
        catch{throw}
        }

    Function Get-FormVariables{
    if ($global:ReadmeDisplay -ne $true){Write-host "If you need to reference this display again, run Get-FormVariables" -ForegroundColor Yellow;$global:ReadmeDisplay=$true}
    write-host "Found the following interactable elements from our form" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    get-variable WPF*
    }

    Get-FormVariables

    #===========================================================================
    # Use this space to add code to the various form elements in your GUI
    #===========================================================================

    #setzt die Variablen auf bestimmte Objekte, wodurch das Verändern der Objekte sehr flexibel ist
    $OutputBox = $Form.FindName('textBlock')
    $InputBox = $Form.FindName('textBox')
    $ListBox = $Form.FindName('listBox')


    #Eventhandler
    $InputBox.Add_TextChanged({
        $input = $InputBox.Text


        if($input.length -gt 3){
        $ListBox.Visibility ="Visible"
        $input = "*" + $input + "*"
        $user = @(Get-ADUser -Filter ' Name -like  $input ' | Select -ExpandProperty Name)
        #debug $OutputBox.Text = ($user | ForEach {"{0}`r" -f $_})
        $ListBox.itemsSource = $user
---> Here should be the eventhandler for clicking an item in the listbox <---
        # $listuser = Get-ADUser -Filter ' Name -like  $ListBox.SelectedItem '
        # $OutputBox.Text = $ListBox.SelectedItem

        }

    })





    $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
 $ListBox.add_SelectionChanged({$OutputBox.Text = $ListBox.SelectedItem})
```

---

Personally I prefer creating special function with events and call it before `$Form.ShowDialog()`. Add as much events as you need. Example:

```
         function event_handler
        {
            $textbox_name.add_TextChanged({$textbox_Login.Text = Construct-Login $textbox_name.Text $textbox_LastName.Text})

        }
```

In this example when you type something to the textbox `textbox_name`, function `Construct-Login` is invoked and result is written to another textbox.

By the way, you don't need extra

```
$OutputBox = $Form.FindName('textBlock')
$ListBox = $Form.FindName('listBox')
```

since `$xaml.SelectNodes` does the thing for you. Just make sure you have unique names for all controls at your form.

Comment: Well my problem with SelectionChanged is the fact, that every time you switch the selection, the event is activated. That wouldnt be the problem if you only use the mouse for selection, but the possibility to select with keyboard arrows should be there aswell. And doing that doesn't work with SelectionChanged.

Comment: My approach for now is using $ListBox.Add_KeyDown, which is working fine, but it accepts every Key and I dont know how to bind it to a specific key, for example Enter

Comment: What about using combobox instead? @Hoesl

Comment: As far as I know, combobox doesn't support the TextChanged-Method, which is mandatory for most of my scriptcode.